# SI4T Integration - remove from index information when unpublishing?

Tags: si4t, publishing

Looking at the SI4T documentation, it seems we can only remove item from index after we change the metdata and publish the item again, is there a way we can remove item from the index while unpublishing the item?

I am also looking for how do we cater the scenario of handling multiple indexes, for e.g. I have 5-6 different sites for which I want to maintain separate Indexes and there are some common pages for couple of sites whose index information gets updated in their corresponding indexes, how will un-publish work here, how will it determine from which index it will remove the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you have different Tridion Publications for each of the websites, it is possible to have a separate index for each of the websites. SI4T supports this out of the box. The way to set this up is to configure an index per website publication in `cd_storage_conf.xml`:

```
    <Storage 
            Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="MSSQL" 
            Class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory">
    <!-- ommitted other configuration -->

    <!-- 
        To be able to use multiple cores for a website publication,
        simply add a solr web application core corresponding 
        for a Tridion Publication.

        The example below shows that you can either post to different cores
        on a single solr server, or to a completely different server if so required

        Let's say for example there are 3 publications:

        tcm:0-5-1 : example.com - English main website
        tcm:0-8-1 : example.de - German website, indexed on a separate server
        tcm:0-12-1: example.co.uk - UK only content

        If content is published from a different publication, it will be 
        indexed in the English main website publication Solr core. This is no
        problem, because all content is indexed based on the unique TCM Id and
        a single Solr index can therefore also hold content for multiple publications.

    -->
    <Indexer 
        Class="com.tridion.extensions.storage.search.solr.SolrIndexer" 
        Mode="http"
        DefaultCoreUrl="http://localhost/solr/example-com"
        DocExtensions="pdf,docx,doc,xls,xlsx,pptx,ppt">
        <Urls>
            <Url Value="http://localhost/solr/example-com" Id="5" />
            <Url Value="http://solrindex.example.de/solr/example-de" Id="8" />
            <Url Value="http://localhost/solr/example-couk" Id="12" />
        </Urls>
    </Indexer>
    </Storage>
```

**Pubishing / Unpublishing**

Both publishing and unpublishing work in the same way, regardless whether content is indexed in a single, or in multiple Solr indexes. The SI4T indexer always matches content to be indexed or removed at publish time against the configured Publication Ids set in `cd_storage_conf.xml`. It does this by simply matching the publication Id part of the TCM Id of the Tridion item and then by looking up the correct index to insert, update or remove content.

**Searching multiple indexes**

If the requirement is to have separate indexes, **but** to search across different Solr cores, then I would recommend to take a look at Solr's [Distributed Search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch) capability, which also works out of the box.

Answer (score 5):

Don't worry! The standard behaviour is that when you unpublish an item it will also be removed from the index. The functionality to remove from the index by republishing, is to enable users to un-index pages that are still needed on the site without having to unpublish then republish them.

I updated the [documentation](https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/wiki/FAQ#wiki-how-do-i-remove-a-page-from-the-index), to make this clear.

Comment: Thanks Will, please can you give an idea how this is achieved

Comment: As Will says, the default behaviour is that if a page or a DCP is in the index (as identified by the unique tcm id), it will always be deleted when that item is unpublished. Please read the link Will provided. :)

Comment: @Raimond thanks, I am just wondering how this work if we have multiple indexes, as when I un-publish a page I wont be having page's index information so how do I know from which Index I need to remove the page

Comment: Can you describe your multiple index setup a bit better? It would be good if you edit your post.